# What is the proper way to define CanCan abilities for ActiveRecord inheritance hierarchies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, subclass, cancan

I have a situation where I'd like to define separate abilities for an ActiveRecord class `Thing` and its subclass `SubThing`.  Unfortunately, this isn't quite possible, since it appears that the subclass inherits abilities from its parent.

I started like this:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize
    can :update, Thing
    can :update, SubThing do |st|
      st.editable?
    end
  end
end
```

But this didn't work, `SubThing`s could always be updated, regardless of their `editable?` value, because `SubThing` abilities are inherited from `Thing`, which is always updateable.

I ended like this:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize
    can :update, Thing
    cannot :update, SubThing do |st|
      !st.editable?
    end
  end
end
```

This works: all `Thing`s and `SubThing`s are updateable, excepting those `SubThing`s whose `editable?` value is false.  But IMHO this isn't an intuitive way to set things up, and the Ability class doesn't seem to fully express what I'm trying to achieve.

I'd actually prefer that abilities were not inherited, so that my first approach (which IMHO expresses more clearly what I am after) would work.

Are there better ways to achieve this?

BTW, [this gist](https://gist.github.com/wrkrb33/326c49358b2f57e155b789651c98522c) is an executable test case that I wrote to help understand and eventually solve (work around?) my problem.

Comment: Well I'm not sure this will help, but I usually tend to use Pundit (https://github.com/elabs/pundit) rather than CanCan, as it is, IMHO, a much more flexible and beautiful way to handle this kind of case, through a system of Policies that are just PORO. Hope this help

Comment: @lkartono Yes, I am aware of Pundit, and it does look like a really good alternative to CanCan.  But I am working on a legacy app where CanCan is already in place.